# Xamarin.Forms Debugging

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a Xamarin.Forms application consisting of multiple referenced PCL projects for various functionality.

The problem that I am having is enabling debugging across the projects.

There is definitely a problem within one of the referenced projects but without been able to get into the source it is difficult to trace.

I have done the following:

- Build configurations for each project to ensure they are included in
  the Debug configuration
- Cleaned each project
- Cleaned the solution
- Rebuilt the solution
- Set breakpoints in the various projects

The most interesting point is that a client has the same solution but does not experience the same problem.

Hopefully somebody can shed some light.

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you having? What happens when you debug?

Comment: Nothing happens, it just hangs. It gets to the point in the Xamarin.Forms project but then when it references a method in a different, but referenced, project then it fails.

Comment: It's not a solution, but I thought it might be worth sharing. For me it hangs when I'm stepping over or in the method. If I go to definition and put a breakpoint somewhere inside the method body and let it run until it hits the breakpoint, then it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the pdb files for the projects? Make sure that they exist and loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience. What I do is, simply putting break points in to sub methods if I can't step into them.

And also bear in mind, if you work with async methods, you mush put a break point before and after those methods to debug it as async methods will always crash if you try to debug them.